# Read XML value using TSQL

Tags: xml, t-sql

I would like to retrieve the CUSTOMERNO from this web service response using TSQL. Note that this is the exact xml file I'm getting. Thanks in advance.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body>
  <CreateCustomerResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">  
  <CreateCustomerResult>&lt;RESPONSEINFO&gt;&lt;STATUS&gt;&lt;TRANSACTIONNO&gt;60878693&lt;/TRANSACTIONNO&gt;&lt;ERRORNO&gt;1002&lt;/ERRORNO&gt;&lt;MESSAGE&gt;Success&lt;/MESSAGE&gt;&lt;/STATUS&gt;&lt;CUSTOMERNO&gt;9021325146&lt;/CUSTOMERNO&gt;&lt;/RESPONSEINFO&gt;
 </CreateCustomerResult></CreateCustomerResponse>
 </soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you post some code? did you try anything ?

Comment: How does it come, that you poste an XML fragment and somebody else postes an edit where the XML (and the whole approach) is changed completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your XML is read into a xml typed variable this can be done like here:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<RESPONSEINFO>
  <STATUS>
    <TRANSACTIONNO>60878693</TRANSACTIONNO>
    <ERRORNO>1002</ERRORNO>
    <MESSAGE>Success</MESSAGE>
  </STATUS>
  <CUSTOMERNO>9021325146</CUSTOMERNO>
</RESPONSEINFO>';

SELECT @xml.value(N'(/RESPONSEINFO/CUSTOMERNO)[1]',N'bigint')
```

### UPDATE Your question changed completely... (avoid chameleons please!)

You must first read the wrapped XML and read from there:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateCustomerResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <CreateCustomerResult>&lt;RESPONSEINFO&gt;&lt;STATUS&gt;&lt;TRANSACTIONNO&gt;60878693&lt;/TRANSACTIONNO&gt;&lt;ERRORNO&gt;1002&lt;/ERRORNO&gt;&lt;MESSAGE&gt;Success&lt;/MESSAGE&gt;&lt;/STATUS&gt;&lt;CUSTOMERNO&gt;9021325146&lt;/CUSTOMERNO&gt;&lt;/RESPONSEINFO&gt;
 </CreateCustomerResult>
    </CreateCustomerResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

SELECT CAST(@xml.value(N'(/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:CreateCustomerResponse/*:CreateCustomerResult/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS XML).value(N'(/RESPONSEINFO/CUSTOMERNO)[1]',N'bigint')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is by using below code snippet -

```
DECLARE @xmltext XML = N'<RESPONSEINFO><STATUS><TRANSACTIONNO>60878693</TRANSACTIONNO><ERRORNO>1002</ERRORNO><MESSAGE>Success</MESSAGE></STATUS><CUSTOMERNO>9021325146</CUSTOMERNO></RESPONSEINFO>'     
SELECT T.C.value('CUSTOMERNO[1]', 'varchar(255)') FROM @xmltext.nodes('/RESPONSEINFO') T(C)
```

**Edit:** Based on the changed question, modified the code snippet -

```
DECLARE @xmltext XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
 <CreateCustomerResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">  
 <CreateCustomerResult>&lt;RESPONSEINFO&gt;&lt;STATUS&gt;&lt;TRANSACTIONNO&gt;60878693&lt;/TRANSACTIONNO&gt;&lt;ERRORNO&gt;1002&lt;/ERRORNO&gt;&lt;MESSAGE&gt;Success&lt;/MESSAGE&gt;&lt;/STATUS&gt;&lt;CUSTOMERNO&gt;9021325146&lt;/CUSTOMERNO&gt;&lt;/RESPONSEINFO&gt;
 </CreateCustomerResult>
 </CreateCustomerResponse>
 </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>'      
SELECT CAST(T.C.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS XML).value('(/RESPONSEINFO/CUSTOMERNO)[1]','nvarchar(100)')
FROM @xmltext.nodes('/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:CreateCustomerResponse/*:CreateCustomerResult') T(C)
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can parse it to that format? I tried your code and supplied the exact format (see from original post. The one with soap:Envelope)